# mod_rewrite www.site.com/dir/ --> www.site.com/dir/2009/

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble with this rewrite. I've never really used mod_rewrite before and don't have much experience with regex. Any help is appreciated!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#prevent nested looping
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
#re-route incoming requests
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}2009/$1 [L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

This partially works, http://www.site.com/dir/ is routed to http://www.site.com/dir/2009/ but a request like http://www.site.com/dir/css/theme.css fails. I'm hoping to rewrite all requests to the parent directory into the 2009 subdirectory but I keep encountering infinite loops and server errors messages. I haven't found any useful examples out there. I figured this would be a common rewrite...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh, and Casey: should `/dir/css/theme.css` be rewritten to `/dir/2009/css/theme.css` or `/dir/css/2009/theme.css`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems with the rewrite rule in your example. First of all, it doesn't really do what you want - you don't need `%{REQUEST_URI}` bit. With the original path like `/dir/css/theme.css` REQUEST_URI will contain `/dir/css/theme.css` and $1 will contain `css/theme.css` (matched by `(.*)`) resulting with final URL being `/dir/css/theme.css2009/css/theme.css`. So we need to get rid of the `%{REQUEST_URI}` part which leaves us with following RewriteRule

```
^(.*)$ 2009/$1 [L,NE]
```

that will translate `/dir/css/theme.css` into `/dir/2009/css/theme.css`.

However there's still one problem with that rule as it will cause infinite nesting since (.*) will match any URL. So what happens is that in the first step our example URL gets rewritten to `/dir/2009/css/theme.css`. And since the new URL `/dir/2009/css/theme.css` matches our rule too it will get rewritten again, and then again and again...

So basically we need something that will prevent rewriting URLS that were already rewritten. So if URL already contains `/dir/2009` we want Apache to leave it alone. One way to accomplish that is to add following condition to the rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!/dir/2009).*$
```

with final .htaccess file like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /dir
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!/dir/2009).*$
    #re-route incoming requests
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 2009/$1 [L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Another way to do it is to create .htacess file in dir/2009 directory which will prevent Apache using the one from the parent directory with something like `RewriteEngine off`. Or perhaps `RewriteEngine on` without any rules should do the trick as well.